# anyway to support session level connector configuration for presto

Tags: presto, trino

Based on [Connectors configuration](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector.html), all workers shares the same connectors configuration under catalog folder, which means it will use the same connector configuration for any presto cluster user. E.g., Queries from prestosql user1 and user2 will use same jdbc query config. However, the traditional RDBMS ACL is based on username in JDBC configuration to support isolation. E.g., user1 will use `jdbc:mysql://user1@host:3306` while user2 will use `jdbc:mysql://user2@host:3306`.

Question: is there any pointers or directions to support session level connector configuration within the same presto cluster? e.g., when user1 run a query, it will pickup `jdbc:mysql://user1@host:3306` when using mysql connector while it can switch to `jdbc:mysql://user2@host:3306` when user2 run a query that connects to mysql.

I'm open for any design inputs like using a centralized config management tool like consul or etcd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure this for the MySQL connector catalog properties file:

```
user-credential-name=mysql_user
password-credential-name=mysql_password
```

This allows the user to provide the MySQL username and password as *extra credentials* that are passed directly to the backend MySQL server when running a Presto query:

```
presto --extra-credential mysql_user=user1 --extra-credential mysql_password=secret
```

The credential names `mysql_user` and `mysql_password` are arbitrary and give you flexibility on how to configure it. For example, suppose you have two MySQL catalogs pointing at two different MySQL servers. If both of the servers share the same users, then you would configure both catalogs with the same credential names, allowing the same credentials to be used for both. If they are different, then you would name them differently, e.g., `mysql1_user` and `mysql2_user`, allowing the user to provide different credentials for each catalog.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for this excellent answer and I made a feature for the connector presto-db2: https://github.com/IBM/presto-db2/issues/19

Answer (score 4):

This is directly supported by use of extra credentials.
See https://github.com/trinodb/trino/blob/8c1a4a10abaad91a2f4656653a3f5eb0e44aa6c1/presto-base-jdbc/src/main/java/io/prestosql/plugin/jdbc/credential/ExtraCredentialProvider.java#L26

See documentation tasks for more information:

- https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/1910
- https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/1911

Comment: Thank you for following it up! I linked it in https://github.com/IBM/presto-db2/issues/19

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using Starburst Presto, then there is also an option of user impersonation. See https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/security/impersonation.html. Among others, it is currently supported for PostgreSql, but not yet for MySql connector.

Comment: This looks fancy. is there any guide/doc to support such feature for a connector? I want to add this into https://github.com/IBM/presto-db2